# AWS Pool.Signup won't execute code inside block at Swift 3

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, swift3

Ok, I'm starting to work with AWS Cognito and got stuck at User Sign up...

This is where my problem is happening:

```
    func register(userNameChosen:String, attributes:[AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]) {
    let task = self.pool.signUp(userNameChosen, password: senhaTextField.text!, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil)

    task.continue(with: AWSExecutor.default(), with: { (task) -> Any? in

            if task.error != nil { //error occur
                let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: task.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



            } else { //no error
                print("no error")
                let response:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse = task.result! as AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse
                self.user = response.user

                if response.userConfirmed as! Int != AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed.rawValue { //user not confirmed via email
                    //setup para mandar atraves de Segue
                    self.sentTo = response.codeDeliveryDetails?.destination
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confirmSignUp", sender: self)

                } else { 
                    print("User already confirmed?")
                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) //back to login      
                }

            }

        return nil
    }).waitUntilFinished()
}
```

the problem is that the code below

```
task.continue(with: AWSExecutor.default(), with: { (task) -> Any? in
```

won't execute...
The app is already communicating with AWS well. When I run it with "Sign In Optional", even unauthenticated it gets the AWS Token. But when I set Login to Required at Mobile Hub - Cognito, I get the following messages (which I don't think are part of the problem since before you sign up you are Obviously unauthenticated):

```
[26851:2009541] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.9 [Error] AWSIdentityProvider.m line:304 | __52-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper getIdentityId]_block_invoke255 | GetId failed. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}]
```

Or

```
[26851:2009539] [] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 1 
2016-10-04 21:02:33.759918 App Aws[26851:2009462] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. The problem is that it if doesn't get a 'response' from AWSTask, it won't get inside that block and neither throw an error.

I had configured my credentials somehow mistaken so it couldn't attach to my UserPool.

Here is the code I used, if anyone is using Swift 3.0.

```
let serviceConfiguration:AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration.init(region: .usEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)

    let configuration:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE", clientSecret: PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE, poolId: "PUT_YOUR_POOL_ID_HERE")
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: configuration, forKey: "UserPool")

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration
```

If your client secret is blank, use nil, don't use "". I strongly advise you to use a client secret.